# What is the difference between sudo -i and sudo su -

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, bash, command-line-interface

What is the difference between commands `sudo -i` and `sudo su -`?

Are they the same?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They may provide functionally close to the same thing, but it seems 'sudo -i' is lighter weight and keeps some handy back references in your environment.

You can see the extra processes by looking at 'ps auxf' (f gives you a forest view)

**sudo -i**  yields this process tree

```
jkrauska  4480  0.0  0.0  76828  1656 ?        S    23:38   0:00  |   \_ sshd: jkrauska@pts/0
jkrauska  4482  0.0  0.0  21008  3816 pts/0    Ss   23:38   0:00  |       \_ -bash
root      4675  0.6  0.0  19512  2260 pts/0    S+   23:42   0:00  |           \_ -bash
```

**sudo su -** yields this process tree

```
jkrauska  4480  0.0  0.0  76828  1656 ?        S    23:38   0:00  |   \_ sshd: jkrauska@pts/0
jkrauska  4482  0.0  0.0  21008  3816 pts/0    Ss   23:38   0:00  |       \_ -bash
root      4687  0.5  0.0  43256  1488 pts/0    S    23:42   0:00  |           \_ su -
root      4688  0.5  0.0  19508  2252 pts/0    S+   23:42   0:00  |               \_ -su
```

Note that they are starting from the same bash process pid, 4482, but that su - seems to spawn another step.)

Your first 'sudo' is already elevating your access level to root. Running su without specifying a username inside sudo changes the current user to root twice.

Another way to investigate this is by running both commands with strace -f.

```
strace -f -o sudoi sudo -i
```

vs

```
strace -f -o sudosu sudo su -
```

If you diff those two straces, you'll see more exeve's being run for sudo su -.

One more thing.

**sudo -i** maintains the extra environment variables set by SUDO.

```
SUDO_USER=jkrauska
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash
SUDO_GID=1000
```

sudo su -  clobbers those variables.

Comment: Thanks, I voted you as the correct answer. One more question, so is `sudo su -` pointless?

Comment: If you wanted to clobber the SUDO back references it could be useful.  So not pointless in that case.

Comment: There are also big differences in argument handling, environment variable handling, and in security when becoming a non-root user. See what I added here: http://serverfault.com/q/601140/102814

Answer (score 0):

**Shot answer:** No, they are not the same.

**Long answer:** sudo and su - are different programs that accomplish the same task, that is elevating you to root privileges.

**su** used to be the de facto way of becoming root on Linux systems. However there was always the need to separate privileges and leave some auditing info behind. Also when you do **su -** everything you do is done as root and is dangerous to have that much power. Here is where sudo came to the rescue.

**sudo** has some characteristics that **su** does not. The key element in sudo is it's ability to to run "one" command as root and then drop privileges to normal user. 
*Example: Remove a file owned by root.*

```
sudo rm /root/someFile
```

This command will erase the file because sudo will elevate you to root every time you use the sudo command before another command. The next command you ran will be run like a normal user (unless you append the sudo command in the beginning). This allows you to accomplish administrative task and then drop privileges immediately helping you avoid dangerous conditions.

sudo also provides other benefits likes restricting the set of program a user can run, logs commands run under sudo and other things. For more info [sudo in a nutshell](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/intro.html)

When you do *su -* or *sudo -i* you do the same thing. That is becoming root but keep in mind that *su* and *sudo* are completely different and provide you with different tools as a system admin. Personally I NEVER run su - and my [pam policy prohibits it](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/restrict-the-use-of-su-command.html), allowing no one to run it. In my systems you always have to use sudo cause of the added benefits.

More info: [Using and enabling sudo](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/allow-a-normal-user-to-run-commands-as-root.html)

Comment: `su` can also run just a single command: `su -c 'command ...'`

Comment: The question was about the difference between `sudo -i` and `sudo su -`, not between `sudo` and `su`.